# Upload file from Node to remote server

Tags: node.js

I have a situation where I upload file from browser, that goes to node layer and then I have to send it again to another remote server. I am new to node and unable to find any way to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you show what you have tried ? Stackoverflow is not a website to do the work for you. You need to show you made efforts toward a solution.

Comment: look at `request` npm module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to archive file is the physical in determined directory in your server. 
First you create the form, some like this:

```
<form action='/url/to/post method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <input name='image' id="image" type='file'/>
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

After you have to create the route and controller.
The side node.js. I suggest you use **File** and **Formidable** to storage the file.

**File:** https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html.

**Formidable** is a node.js module for parsing form data, especially file uploads: https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable

This is the example how to use it (controller):

```
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {            
        var image = files.image,
            image_upload_path_old = image.path,
            image_upload_path_new = '/path/server',
            image_upload_name = image.name,
            image_upload_path_name = image_upload_path_new;

            if (fs.existsSync(image_upload_path_new)) {
                fs.rename(image_upload_path_old, image_upload_path_name, function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log('Err: ', err);
                    }
                });
             }
    }
```

This is with Express framework (http://expressjs.com/) example.